# Typescript assert type of API response with a base API type

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've written a simple wrapper around `fetch` to talk to an API that returns a list of items, each of which is guaranteed to have at least an `id` property:

```js
type fetchOptions = {};
type fetchReturn = {
  items: Array<{
    id: number;
    [key: string]: any;
  }>;
};

export const get = async (
  path: string,
  options: fetchOptions = {}
): Promise<fetchReturn> => {
  const resp = await fetch(`${API_HOST}${path}`, {
    method: 'GET',
    ...options,
  });
  return resp.json();
};
```

Now in a component, I want to use it to fetch a list of `Todos`, for which I have a type:

```js
type Todo = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  status: string;
};

interface TodosResponse {
  items: Array<Todo>;
}

get('/todos').then((resp: TodosResponse) => { // I know resp.items is a list of Todo
  this.setState({
    todos: resp.items,
  });
});
```

The compiler is giving me this error:

```
Argument of type '(resp: TodosResponse) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: fetchReturn) => void | PromiseLike<void>'.
```

What is the best way to tell the TS compiler that I know what the promise resolution value of `get` will be (because I'm passing `/todos`).

I can loosen the constraints on `fetchReturn` like this, but I'm wondering if there is a better way to indicate *a list of objects which will all have at least an `id` property*:

```
type fetchReturn = {
  items: Array<any>;
}
```

I'm relatively new to TS so any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is correct. The code you are writing isn't type safe. A good rule of thumb in typescript is that if you have to specify the type of a callback parameter then you are doing something wrong.

An elegant way to handle this kind of situation is to correlate the requested URL segment with the assumed type of the response.

```
interface Endpoints {
  '/todos': TodosResponse;
  // etc.
}

export const get = async <Endpoint extends keyof Endpoints>(
  path: Endpoint,
  options: fetchOptions = {}
): Promise<Endpoints[Endpoint]> {
  const resp = await fetch(`${API_HOST}${path}`, {
    method: 'GET',
    ...options,
  });
  return resp.json();
};
```

now you can call it like so

```
get('/todos').then(resp => {
  console.log(resp.items[0].name.split(' '));
});
```

Note how the parameter type is inferred.